# Laravel Intervention/Image after save the filesize didn´t update

Tags: laravel, intervention

I'm working in a simple image optimizer, but I have a problem, I open the image with make,  get the filesize and give me the right value, then try to save with other name with different quality, I slowdown the quality one by one until the file size is less than 100. But the problem is that the filesize never change:

```
if ($data['picture'][$key]['weight'] >= 100) {

   if (@copy(public_path() . '/photos/' . $images['path'], public_path() . '/photos/temp/'. $images['path'])) {

      $img = Image::make(public_path() . '/photos/temp/'. $images['path']);
      $height = $img->height();
      $width = $img->width();

      if ($height > 600) {
        $img->resize(null, 600, function ($constraint) {
           $constraint->aspectRatio();
           $constraint->upsize();
        });
      }

      $height = $img->height();
      $width = $img->width();

      if ($width > 800) {
        $img->resize(800, null, function ($constraint) {
           $constraint->aspectRatio();
           $constraint->upsize();
        });
      }

      $height = $img->height();
      $width = $img->width();

      $size = $img->filesize() / 1000;
      $quality = 100;
```

At this point I get the correct file size, but now, if I destroy the image, and use make again the image is damaged, if I simply open with make again, the image is damaged too. And with this, give me the original size:

```
    while ($size > 100) {
      $img->save(public_path() . '/photos/temp/' . $images['path'])->encode('jpg', $quality)->filesize() / 1000;
      dump($img->filesize());
      if ($size <= 100) {
        break; 
      } else {
        $quality--;
      }

      if ($quality < 80) {
        $size = 100;
        break;
      }

    };

    $data['photos'][$key]['temporal'] = '/photos/temp' . $images['path'];
  }
}
```